# Use loop to conditionally retry a script

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple script that reads an excel file of player ID's, creates a dict of 2 columns and maps those 2 columns to update player ID's in a dataframe. What I'm attempting to do is create a loop where I can print any players that don't have corresponding ID's in the excel file, manually update the excel file myself and then retry the script.

So far I have gotten to the point of asking to run again, but on the 2nd try the mapping line identifies all IDs as missing, which I assume means there is an issue either reading the excel file or the original frame. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
def main(frame):

    while True:
        playerlist = read_csv('PlayerList').fillna(0)

        frame.iloc[:,0] = frame.iloc[:,0].astype(float).map(dict(zip(playerlist['old_id'], playerlist['new_id'])))

        missing = frame[frame.iloc[:,0].isnull()]
        print(missing) #See which players have missing ID's      

        run_again = input('Run again? ') #Fix missing ID's in the excel file, then type 'y' to retry
        if run_again == 'y':
            continue
        else:
            return frame
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem may be caused by the modification of the `frame`.

On the first run, `frame[0]` has what is considered `old_ids`. On the second run, however, they have already been replaced, and `frame[0]` contains `new_ids` instead.

When `.map` is called on a column with `new_ids`, no value is found (we expect `old_ids`), and, therefore, all ids appear to have gone missing.

As a fix, you can calculate the `new_ids` as a local variable, instead of modifying the original DataFrame. For example:

```
def main(frame):

    while True:
        playerlist = read_csv('PlayerList').fillna(0)

        new_ids = frame.iloc[:,0].astype(float).map(dict(zip(playerlist['old_id'], playerlist['new_id'])))

        missing = frame[new_ids.isnull()]
        print(missing) #See which players have missing ID's      

        run_again = input('Run again? ') #Fix missing ID's in the excel file, then type 'y' to retry
        if run_again == 'y':
            continue
        else:
            return frame
```

Comment: BTW, it's difficult to debug without the original data, so I can't be sure if what I said was right :)

Comment: I ended up getting it fixed doing something different but your remarks definitely helped get me in the right direction. Thanks for the input.